# How to display local SKProduct price in UILabel?

Tags: swift

**I want to get localised in app purchase price with currency symbol and display it on UILabel. But I don't know how to do that since I don't know how to get SKProduct object. Maybe it's possible to get it using apple product id?**

```
extension SKProduct {

/// - returns: The cost of the product formatted in the local currency.
var regularPrice: String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
    return formatter.string(from: self.price)
}}
```

EDIT:

```
let productIds: [String] = ["id1", "id2"]
getProducts(productIdentifiers: productIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

> SKProduct objects are returned as part of an SKProductsResponse
>   object. (c) [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct)

How to fetching product information: [Fetching Product Information from the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/fetching_product_information_from_the_app_store)

Also take a look to useful video from WWDC: [Using Store Kit for In-App Purchases with Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/702/)

Summarizing above documentation:

```
class ProductResolver: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    // Keep a strong reference to the product request.
    var request: SKProductsRequest!

    func getProducts(productIdentifiers: [String]) {
        let productIdentifiers = Set(productIdentifiers)
        request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }

    // SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol method.
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        for product in response.products {
            print("Local currency \(product.regularPrice)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my question and added the code how I'm calling this function inside viewDidLoad(). But I'm still not sure how to display product id1 price on UILabel?

Comment: You can use IBOutlets with storyboards or nib. Or you can create UILabel programmatically. After all text to UILabel is setup through [text property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text)